# Access Query- how to get the maxium of several columns

Tags: ms-access

I have about 20 columns in a query and want to get the maximum amount in the last column.  I tried the `iif(a>b,a,iif(b>c,b,c))` but it doesn't work because `a`, `b`, `c` are not listed by any of orders.
Is there any formula I could use please?

[image]

Comment: We will be much more able to help you if your include your query code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following User-defined function (UDF):

```vb
Function Max(ParamArray a() As Variant) As Variant

    Max = Empty ' return value in case of no supplied parameters
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
      If i = LBound(a) Then
        Max = a(i)
      Else
        If Max < a(i) Then Max = a(i)
      End If
    Next i

End Function
```

put it into your VBA module `MyFnc` (if it does not exist, create it) and use its result as

```vb
Max(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t)
```

what will satisfy your use of 20 columns.

Comment: hi Miroxlav, thanks a lot for your fast response! I just have a wonder, but please note I don't have any background in coding, so if I mentioned something wrong here, please let me know. for the iif function you included above, take my original example, the maximum I wanna get is d=$30, but I feel like the function will give me b=$20 because a to e is not sorted from smallest to largest...wouldn't it?

Comment: @miroxlav  Also, it is invalid VBA syntax (at least in Access) to prefix a standard module name to the function name.  As long as it is declared public, just call it directly with no qualification: `Max(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t)`

Comment: @CPerkins – thank you again. I tested calling from code, but not calling from query. Now I recall that 13 years ago, when I extensively programmed in Access it worked like you describe.

Comment: it says "the expression you entered has a function containing the wrong number of arguments......

Comment: I reworked on it and it's working now!!thank you so much